# Toggling Different Classes .click()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two menu items that drop down into a fixed position 'mega menu' (defined by class .has_children). However the following jQuery means that I can click both drop down menus and they will overlay on top of each other; what I want is for no more than 1 menu to be visible at any one time. i.e. the current one hides and the one clicked becomes visible.

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('li.has_children a').click(function() {
    $(this).closest($('li.has_children')).find('ul.sec_nav').toggleClass('is_hidden');
  });

});
```

**HTML**

```
<li class="has_children"><a href="#">Games</a>
  <ul class="is_hidden sec_nav">
    <li>
      <h4>Board Games</h4>
      <ul class="is_hidden">
        <li>Listing</li>
        <li>Listing</li>
        <li>Listing</li>
        <li>Listing</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>

<li class="has_children"><a href="#">Computers</a>
  <ul class="is_hidden sec_nav">
    <li>
      <h4>Windows</h4>
      <ul class="is_hidden">
        <li>Listing</li>
        <li>Listing</li>
        <li>Listing</li>
        <li>Listing</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: HTML added for clarity

Comment: does the below answer meets your requirements?

Comment: Yep, I've published the final working jQuery off the back of Arun's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can just add the class to other elements to hide them

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('li.has_children a').click(function() {
    var $target = $(this).closest('li.has_children').find('ul.sec_nav').toggleClass('is_hidden');
    $('li.has_children ul.sec_nav').not($target).addClass('is_hidden')
  });

});
```

```css
.is_hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="has_children"><a href="#">Games</a>
    <ul class="is_hidden sec_nav">
      <li>
        <h4>Board Games</h4>
        <ul class="is_hidden">
          <li>Listing</li>
          <li>Listing</li>
          <li>Listing</li>
          <li>Listing</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="has_children"><a href="#">Computers</a>
    <ul class="is_hidden sec_nav">
      <li>
        <h4>Windows</h4>
        <ul class="is_hidden">
          <li>Listing</li>
          <li>Listing</li>
          <li>Listing</li>
          <li>Listing</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Arun, I believe the jQuery was slightly off as you included toggleClass in the variable for $target? I will add the code I had working to the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Using Arun's jQuery I have the following working:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

$('li.has_children a').click(function() {
    var $target = $(this).closest('li.has_children').find('ul.sec_nav');
    $(this).closest('li.has_children').find('ul.sec_nav').toggleClass('is_hidden');
    $('li.has_children ul.sec_nav').not($target).addClass('is_hidden')
  });


});
```